# react native push notification doesn't work in Android 8.1 (API level 27)

Tags: android, react-native, android-8.0-oreo, localnotification, react-native-push-notification

In my react native app, I tried to handle Scheduled locale Notifications using this library [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) , it work's fine in devices that runs android API's under 25, so the problem occurs in android Oreo version, I have tried a lot of solutions, like using channels and add a notification to that channel, but without result, Help please!!!

***My react native version*** :

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.58.5

From android Project :

```
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this problem myself after spending several days looking for a solution !!

Go to the file in android project for  [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) library and make some changes [here](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationHelper.java)

From [line 572](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/ae4f9fd06dc46011e4c25f842f00462d7b4d35d2/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationHelper.java#L572) , [To line](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/ae4f9fd06dc46011e4c25f842f00462d7b4d35d2/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationHelper.java#L577)

replace those lines by :

```
NotificationChannel mChannel = manager.getNotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
if (mChannel == null) {
mChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
mChannel.enableVibration(true);
mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
manager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
}
```

Comment: I am sure you know the reason behind the changes you made if not let me add that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

react native push notification doesn't work in >=o because of battery optimization...

Add channel in MAinActivity.java

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("channelID", "channelName", importance);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            nMgr.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        nMgr.cancelAll();
    }
```